# Is there a way to shortcut adding handlers to Yesod?

Tags: haskell, routes, yesod

I'm just starting out in Haskell and Yesod. To get my feet wet, I'm going to convert a small project that I wrote in MVC into Haskell. My first step was just to get all the routes defined.

All told, I have 8 handlers to make this project run.  My routes file looks like this:

```
/activity ActivityR GET
/activity/#String ActivityItemR POST DELETE

/dashboard/month MonthDashboardR GET
/dashboard/year YearDashboardR GET

/calendar CalendarR GET

/events/calendar CalendarEventsR GET
/events/report ReportEventsR GET

/report ReportR GET
```

The flow I went through in adding these routes went like this:

1. Add route to config/routes
2. Create file in Handler folder (I created one for each route parent, e.g. /events or /dashboard)
3. Add an import to the handler created in step #2 to Application.hs
4. Add the handler file name to my project's cabal file

Is there a shortcut, or way to wildcard these handlers so that I could do something like `Import Handler.*`

Or is the preferred way to have fewer handler modules that handle multiple different routes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `yesod` command line tool provides the command `add-handler` which will automate much of this.

Comment: To clarify, you should run `yesod add-handler` with no arguments. It will prompt you for more information. If you call it with an argument, you get a slightly confusing `Usage: yesod add-handler` message.